# How to copy Div content in to Input value real time?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I need to copy real time div content in to input value.
Here I have code:
http://jsfiddle.net/dainis/Xjsp5/
I need that text in #preces_slug will appears in url_slug in real time. I need it becouse have php code for id that I need in url, that is why I cant use friendurl to directly change title to url.
Thanks.

Comment: HTML pages should have unique id's !!

Comment: Please include all code in that jsfiddle additionally inside your question. Fiddles may disappear with time, this question is useless without.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a `keydown` event and it will copy out the value transliterated anywhere you want.

```
$(function() {
    $('.preces_nosaukums').friendurl({
        id: 'url_slugs',
        transliterate: true
    });

    $('.preces_nosaukums').keydown(function() {
        $('#url_slug').val($('#url_slugs').text());
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3zE3p/

Comment: Function $('#url_slug').val($('#url_slugs').text());
 copy input value into div text, but is is possible to other side: from div text to value, something like that: $('#url_slugs').textl($('#url_slug').val());

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why you would do this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a handler js function that is called by some event. When called that function takes the content from the div (using jquery) and sets it into the inputs value.